# Python class initialized with array as default value

Tags: python

I recently discovered a strange behavior with a simple situation.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, data=[]):
        self.data = data

    def add(self, data):
        self.data.append(data)
    
    def see(self):
        return self.data

r = MyClass()
r.add("nice item")
print(r.see())

u = MyClass()
print(u.see())
```

Running this script returned this

```
['nice item']
['nice item']
```

How is that possible ? I assume r and u are different instance of MyClass but u return data added into r. Anybody can explain ?

Comment: The default argument `data` to the constructor method is mutable - if you're using an IDE like Pycharm, it similarly also complains and warns you that unexpected results like this can occur.

Comment: The solution is to define the `__init__` as so:  `def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data or []`. This results in an expected result of `['nice item']
[]`.

Comment: Yes, this is the workaround I made, thanks for your answer !